Bound on Number of Edges in Unit Distance Graphs in $R^3$
This is a homework problem:
I'm asked to find an asymptotic bound for edges in unit distance graph of n vertices in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
I have an idea, but it's not formal, and I'm not sure if it's correct:
Considering a cube in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I can "copy" it and put the copied cube next to the original, and joining the n vertices in such a way that we get the following recursive recurrence: $$A(2n) = A(n) + n $$
Giving us $A(n) = O(nlogn) $
I'm not sure if this is correct, I'd appreciate any help.

This looks like Turán's Theorem could potentially help here, just of the top off my head
